# Where should I post a question regarding GPUs?

Tags: support, scope

I installed the libraries and the framework for using a GPU when training deep learning models. While everything works fine, I'm having trouble recovering data about its usage. Is Stack Overflow the appropriate place for asking this question?

Comment: That's much too vague. Look at the docs/tutorials for the framework you're using. If you have a _specific_ usage/API question, SO should be fine though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Questions about GPUs can be on-topic on Stack Overflow - we even have a [gpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gpu) tag. But the issue you describe seems to be too broad for a typical Stack Overflow question. Read up on the documentation, and if you're stuck, *then* you probably have a question which is narrow enough.

Comment: Ok, the question was about a problem during the installation of a deep learning module using GPU, however I solved the issue. I'll keep that in mind for the future. Thanks.